# HTTP POST using Telegram Webhook

Tags: curl, telegram, telegram-bot, webhooks, telegram-webhook

I have an endpoint that I run using curl command

`curl -X POST https://example.com/control -d "channel=X&turn=XXX&id=XXXXXX&auth_key=XXXXX"`

I want to bind between Telegram Webhook and that POST , so each time my Telegram bot will get a message it POST to that URL

I tried to register a Telegram webhook:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot<telegram_token>/setWebhook?url=https://example.com/control?channel=X&turn=XXX&id=XXXXXX&auth_key=XXXXX`

But then I see that the POST sent only for

`https://example.com/control?channel=X`

Is there a way to attach more data using Telegram webhook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `curl` understands additional query parameters (`turn`, `id`, `auth_key`) to be parameters for `https://api.telegram.org`, not for the url that you pass in the `url` parameter. You can check this with https://httpbin.org :

```bash
curl -X POST https://httpbin.org/anything -d "url=https://example.com/control?channel=X&turn=XXX&id=XXXXXX&auth_key=XXXXX"
```

The returned object contains:

```json
"form": {
    "auth_key": "XXXXX",
    "id": "XXXXXX",
    "turn": "XXX",
    "url": "https://example.com/control?channel=X"
},
```

Solution is to use `--data-urlencode` flag instead of `-d` (which is `--data`):

```bash
curl -X POST "https://httpbin.org/anything" --data-urlencode "url=https://example.com/control?channel=X&turn=XXX&id=XXXXXX&auth_key=XXXXX"
```

Response:

```json
"form": {
    "url": "https://example.com/control?channel=X&turn=XXX&id=XXXXXX&auth_key=XXXXX"
},
```

Telegram request:

```bash
curl -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<telegram_token>/setWebhook --data-urlencode "url=https://example.com/control?channel=X&turn=XXX&id=XXXXXX&auth_key=XXXXX"
```

Comment: See my comment in your question.